# Xamarin Grid Height changes after Images Loaded

Tags: xamarin, grid

As i shows in attached images, my grid row is square shaped space before connecting to server and load the images, but when images are loaded it changes it's height and become rectangle shape. how can i avoid it ? i want to keep the square shaped space.

my photos are also squared.

before and after after connecting to server
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZj6F.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaKQd.png

Code :



<Grid.RowDefinitions>


</Grid.RowDefinitions>

```
                        <Image x:Name="imgStation1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" BackgroundColor="White" Source="saturday.jpg"  Aspect="AspectFill" />
                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Spacing="10" Margin="10">
                            <Label x:Name="lblLiveStation1"  Text="" FontSize="Small" TextColor="AntiqueWhite">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform
                         x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                         Android="gothic.ttf#gothic"
                         iOS="Optima-Regular" />
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="lblDescriptionStation1"  Text="Loading..." FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="FloralWhite">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform
                         x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                         Android="gothic.ttf#gothic"
                         iOS="Optima-Regular" />
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                            <Label x:Name="lblTimeStation1"  Text="" FontSize="Small" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="GhostWhite">
                                <Label.FontFamily>
                                    <OnPlatform
                         x:TypeArguments="x:String"
                         Android="gothic.ttf#gothic"
                         iOS="Optima-Regular" />
                                </Label.FontFamily>
                            </Label>
                            <ImageButton x:Name="imgPlayPause0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="playlogo.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="imgPlayPause0_Clicked"></ImageButton>
                        </StackLayout>
 </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving `Aspect="Fill"` ?

If you want to have image with height = width(i.e., Square), then give hardcoded width or height to it.

If that is not possible in your case, then try using `RelativeSource` where `WidthHeight ="*"` and height will be relative to Width like this `WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference Self}, Path=WidthRequest}}"`

Comment: Thanks Heightrequest did the job. Aspect=Fill doesnt fix the problem it just streched my image on small rectangle space.